# No puedo ocultar <div> en parent desde <iframe> hijo

Tags: javascript, iframe, javascript-objeto

Tengo una página PRINCIPAL con un reproductor de musica (aparte del JavaScript para controlar Play/Pause, claro):

```
    var cancion = new Audio('https://miMusica.mp3');
```

Y un IFRAME que ocupa toda la pantalla:

```
    <iframe id="appPrincipal" width="100%" height="100%" src="miPagina.html"></iframe>
```

En la página PRINCIPAL también tengo un botón fijo para que, aunque cambie el contenido (url) del IFRAME, la música siga sonando y la pueda controlar mediante dicho botón, que es un DIV:

```
    <div id="musika" class="reproductor" onclick="playPause()"><i class="material-icons volume_off" style="right: 93px;">&#xe04f;</i></div>
```

Como hay páginas que se cargarán en el IFRAME que tienen gráficos y otros elementos en la misma posición que está el botón del reproductor, en esas páginas en concreto quiero ocultar el botón del reproductor.

DESDE EL IFRAME he probado de estas 2 maneras y no logro ocultar el botón de la página PRINCIPAL (PARENT):

```
    objeto = window.parent.document.getElementById('musika');
    objeto.style.display = 'none';

    // -------------------------------

    objeto = window.top.document.getElementById('musika');
    objeto.style.display = 'none';
```

Y también de forma directa, pero tampoco hay manera:

```
    window.top.document.getElementById('musika').style.display = 'none';

    // -------------------------------

    window.parent.document.getElementById('musika').style.display = 'none';
```

También me valdría alguna forma de ejecutar una función JavaScript desde el IFRAME y que se ejecute en la página PADRE. He estado mirando por Internet y tampoco lo logro hacer.

¿Me podéis echar un cable, por favor? Espero haberme explicado bien.
Muchas gracias con antelación ;)

Comment: Prueba con .style.visibility = 'hidden';

Comment: También lo he probado y tampoco hace nada. Aunque lo que quiero es algo más que ocultarlo, también quiero que, aunque esté oculto, no ocupe sitio.

De todas formas, muchas gracias por la respuesta ;)

Comment: Prueba creando una función (ej: `functionEnPrincipal()`)en **PRINCIPAL** que haga un `console.log('functionFromPrincipal')` e intenta hacer dentro del **IFRAME** un `window.parent.functionEnPrincipal()` para saber si funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he resuelto, compis. ¡Muchas gracias a todos por vuestro interés!

Lo tenía todo correctamente, el problema era del navegador (probado con Chrome, Firefox y Opera), que bloquea ciertos servicios. He instalado un servidor (WAMP en este caso) y va como la seda.

Muchas gracias nuevamente ;)

PD: gracias a la respuesta de **Roy Bogado** di con el fallo, ya que nunca me había dado por usar la cónsola ;)